# How can I aquire (not avoid) sour blueberries?

Tags: ripe, blueberries

If I'm specifically looking for sour blueberries, what can I do to best avoid the sweet ones?

If buying from the store, do I just look for berries that are more red? 
Perhaps there is a particular time of year when they'll be more sour?

Comment: One idea for a very similar but more tart taste would be to try to track down huckleberries.  A stronger flavor more like wild lowbush blueberries but even ripe they tend to have more bite as long as they have not been artificially sweetened.  If you find red ones rather than blue/black they will tend to be even more tart.

Comment: What is your end goal with them? Eating out of hand or baking? Smoothies?

Comment: @Catija - The possibilities are limitless :)

Comment: Mostly I was asking because if you're planning to puree or cook them, you might find companies selling them frozen... but if you just want to eat them out of hand, you won't like that.

Comment: I might find companies selling them frozen...sour?

Comment: Try to LAB ferment them, perhaps? Or mix with some rhubarb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too love sour blueberries. I usually shake the punnet **gently** in the shop, and if they 'rattle' like they're hard, they will often be fairly sour. If they just thud around quietly, they are probably ripe and sweet.

The same theory can be applied to picking blueberries - go for the firmer ones.

In the UK, the time of year that is best for sourness is around May/Early June for British-grown blueberries. Slightly earlier for Polish or Spanish berries (I find Polish are often the best - tart but full of flavour)

Answer (score 3):

Blueberries don't continue to ripen after picking so finding those that are blue and tart can be a challenge. If you see berries that are slightly purple or red, they may have been picked early and be a bit tart.

If you're in an area where blueberries are raised, you might visit early in the season, which is late July to mid August. Picking your own might do it, or finding a wild blueberry patch. And if you're really into them and have the ability, consider planting your own bush; early Spring is the time to do it.